# Multiple levels of @Mock and @InjectMocks

Tags: java, mockito

So I understand that in Mockito `@InjectMocks` will inject anything that it can with the annotation of `@Mock`, but how to handle this scenario?

```java
    @Mock
    private MockObject1 mockObject1;
    
    @Mock
    private MockObject2 mockObject2;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest();
```

Imagine that `MockObject2` has an attribute that is of type `MockObject1`, and `SystemUnderTest` has an attribute of type `MockObject2`. I would like to have `mockObject1` injected into `mockObject2`, and `mockObject2` injected into `systemUnderTest`.

Is this possible with annotations?

Comment: You don't seem to be using Spring, else it's pretty easy to mock a bean (doesn't matter the level of mock) using "@MockBean" instead of "@Mock".

Comment: Emphasizing the response of @ManojkumarKhotele here; it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since I didn't get any response here I asked on the Mockito forums. Here is a link to the discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mockito/hWwcI5UHFi0/discussion

To summarize the answers, technically this would kind of defeat the purpose of mocking. You should really only mock the objects needed by the `SystemUnderTest` class. Mocking things within objects that are themselves mocks is kind of pointless.

If you really wanted to do it, `@Spy` can help.

Comment: Yes, it's not appropriate for *unit* tests where mocking is used, but this feature (injecting dependencies all the way down) can be very useful for *integration* tests. I am currently working on it for my own mocking toolkit, JMockit.

Answer (score 31):

It is possible by combining @Spy with @InjectMocks. For your example, it would be:

```
@Spy
private MockObject1 mockObject1 = new MockObject1 ();

@Spy @InjectMocks //if MockObject2 has a MockObject1, then it will be injected here.
private MockObject2 mockObject2 = new MockObject2 ();

@InjectMocks
private SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest;
```

Comment: This is no longer encouraged with mockito2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567326/is-it-discouraged-to-use-spy-and-injectmocks-on-the-same-field
and
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/169

Answer (score 20):

Other solution I found is using java sintax instead annotation to make the @Spy object injected.

```
@Spy
private MockObject1 mockObject1 = new MockObject1 ();

@InjectMocks //if MockObject2 has a MockObject1, then it will be injected here.
private MockObject2 mockObject2 = spy(MockObject2.class);

@InjectMocks
private SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest;
```

Comment: this is the best solution, fields with both `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks` do not get injected and replacing `@Spy` with `spy(XXXClass.class)` works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
private MockObject1 mockObject1 = mock(MockObject1.class);

@Spy
private RealObject2 realObject = new RealObject2(mockObject1);

@InjectMocks
private SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest();
```

Comment: This is not really injection though, since you just send your MockObject1 to MockObject2 using the constructor.

Comment: Hmm, well, one could call this constructor injection. Used to a first class citizen until some architecture dictators decided otherwise...

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class DocumentServiceTestMock {

//2nd Level Dependency
CustomerFacade customerFacade = Mockito.mock(CustomerFacade.class);

//Direct Dependency
@Spy
PostCreateHelper postCreateHelper = new PostCreateHelper(customerFacade);

//SUT
@InjectMocks
DocumentService documentService;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
        given(customerFacade.getString()).willReturn("customerFacade_MOCKED");
}

@Test
void test() {
     String documentAsResource = documentService.getDocumentAsResource(ExportType.WORD);
}
//----------
@Service
public class DocumentService {
   final PostCreateHelper postCreateHelper;

@Component
public class PostCreateHelper {
   final CustomerFacade customerFacade;

@Service
public class CustomerFacade {
```