# Is it discouraged to use @Spy and @InjectMocks on the same field?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

In the project I'm working on right now,
I often see the `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks` used together on a field.
I have never seen it this way in any tutorials or other resources.
I googled about this specific combination but didn't
find anything else other than this thread on GitHub:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/169

Which makes me think we are using it in a weird way.

Note: The reason why I think using both annotations together
makes sense sometimes is because if you only use `@InjectMocks`
Mockito tries to instantiate the class with a no-args constructor.
If you don't have a no-args contructor and add `@Spy` you can use the object without needing an empty constructor.

Edit: Another important use is that you can only stub methods
if you just use both annotations.

Comment: Per Baeldung, "Mockito doesn't support injecting mocks into spies", so, "If we want to use a mock with a spy, we can manually inject the mock through a constructor" https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations

Comment: @J. Schneider I also came into such a case. Seems that if you have a DI, if you use Mock to mock the child, the order matters. You have to mock the children first and then only use injectMock on your main class

Answer (score 61, accepted):

@Spy and @InjectMocks cannot be used well together (see [Google Code issue #489](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/issues/489) and [GitHub issue #169](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/169)), and for what they do it is not clear or common that they should be used together at all. In well-written Mockito usage, you generally should not even *want* to apply them to the same object.

- [**@InjectMocks**](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mock.html) works as a sort of stand-in dependency injection for the system under test: If you have a test that defines a @Mock or @Spy of the right type, Mockito will initialize any fields in your @InjectMocks instance with the contents of those test fields. This might be handy if you haven't otherwise structured your system-under-test for dependency injection (or if you use a DI framework that does field injection) and you want to replace those dependencies with mocks. It can be pretty fragile—unmatched fields will be silently ignored and will remain `null` if not set in an initializer—but remains a decent annotation *for your system under test*.
- [**@Spy**](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html), like [@Mock](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mock.html), is designed to set up *test doubles*; you should use it when you have a collaborator that you want to stub or verify. Though there are cases where you *could* spy on your system under test, @Spy and @Mock are meant *for dependencies, and not for the functionality you are testing*.

Ideally, you should not have any class that fulfills both roles in the same test, or else you may find yourself writing a test that painstakingly tests behavior that you've stubbed rather than actual production behavior. In any case it will be more difficult to tell exactly what the test covers versus the behavior you've stubbed.

Of course, this may not apply if you're trying to use Mockito to test a single method in isolation, and you want to stub calls to one method while testing the other. This can be accomplished by creating a spy of your system-under-test and mocking some of its methods to avoid calling collaborators. However, this might also be an indication that your class is violating the Single Responsibility Principle, and that you should break down the class into multiple independent classes that work together. Then, in your test, you can allow instances to have exactly one role and never need both annotations at once.

Comment: Does that correlate with MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()?

Comment: @Igor What do you mean by "correlate"? The call to `initMocks` doesn't throw an exception, but Mockito doesn't do everything you might want to do with both annotations. In addition to the philosophical reasons I wrote about above, see also [issue #489 on Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/issues/489) for limits on the implementation.

Comment: @JeffBowman It is not that uncommon for public methodA to call public methodB of same class. Why would this be a bad design? I already tested methodB individually, and I want to test methodA by stubbing methodB subcall. Is there a better way than having both annotations on same class? Inject self reference maybe?

Comment: @acheron55 Your case is the one I mention in my last paragraph, and that reason stands: If your methods are independent enough to require independent testing, that hints they might belong better to separate classes.  This allows you to be clear about what you're mocking (injected dependencies) and what is real (your whole class under test). I also think you'll find it much easier to reason about your classes—and test their _specifications_ instead of their implementations—if you test methodA against its expected behavior rather than its implementation detail of relying on methodB.

Comment: @acheron55 All that said, you're welcome to take a class instance, fill it with mocks, and then spy on that to replace implementations. It's possible, and I can see it providing value even if it's a little confusing; it just requires _more nuance than Mockito has decided to support via annotations_, so a manual call to `Mockito.spy` is in order. Take care to use `doVerb` methods rather than `when().thenVerb()`, though, so you don't accidentally call the class under test while trying to stub it.

Comment: @acheron55 Ah, as a clarifying point: It's no trouble at all for `methodA` to call `methodB`, and for each to be tested. The trick is in mocking a piece of the class you're testing. In your shoes I'd just test `methodA` against its expected output, test `methodB` against its expected output, and break them up if the implementations are big or heavy enough to want mocking like you describe. After all, `methodB`'s implementation shouldn't creep into the test: what if you refactor them both to use *private* method `methodC`? The tests would be brittle: they'd break while the implementation works.

Answer (score 16):

Each annotation has different purposes and they don't step on each other clearly as long as you need to use partial mocks. (a.k.a. stubbing related method(s) that has been already tested and/or trusted)

For example, you have a class to test, which has dependency injection(s) that doesn't have to be real so you want to @InjectMocks. Besides, the method you are testing calls another method inside, which was already tested somewhere, or it calls external reference which was also tested most likely independently. So, you don't want to be bothered to test same method(s) more than once, and your test code should not be impacted by the out-of-scope implementation change anytime in the future.

Only @Mock & @Spy, or @Mock & @InjectMocks pairs make no sense.

Comment: You won't be able to use Mock & InjectMocks as a pair, or you'll get: "This combination of annotations is not permitted on a single field: @Mock and @InjectMocks"