# How to stub a method of an class annotated with @InjectMocks?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Below `MyDictionary.get` method uses the injected `map` by calling `map.get`.

Just of curiosity I stubbed the `MyDictionary.get` method, like I always do with mocks and spies, so I overwrite the injection.

But this only works when   `MyDictionary.get` indeed calls `map.get`. If `map.get` returns some string (the empty string here), the stub `Mockito.when` does not work. The behavior is as if it is not there. In the assert line, `dictionary.get("key")` equals the empty string. This is what I do not understand.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {

    @Mock
    Map<String, String>map;

    @InjectMocks
    MyDictionary dictionary;

    @Test
    public void testMyDictionary(){
        Mockito.when(dictionary.get("key")).thenReturn("value");
        Assert.assertEquals("value", dictionary.get("key"));
    }

    private static class MyDictionary{
        private Map<String, String> map; 
        public String get(String key){
            return map.get(key);
// or,
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to mock the get method of Dictionary or the get method of injected map and call real Dictionary.get method?

Comment: You can't use `when` on something that is not a mock or spy, and `@InjectMocks` implies it is your real system under test, not a mock or spy. See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38573651/1426891) for a bit about why this can pose a problem even when making `dictionary` a spy.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I wanted to stub the `MyDictionary.get` method, but when I 'do' that with the `when` call above, I see that by doing this I stub the `map.get` method! This is what I do not understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am really surprised that you do not get a `MissingMethodInvocationException` which is thrown when you try to stub a method of an object not being a @Mock or a @Spy.

The `dictionary` instance is just a regular instance of a class here not proxied by Mockito (because of the fact that only @InjectMocks annotation is used).

Another surprise is that you do not get a `null` when the `map.get` is triggered as default return value for a String returning method is `null`.

Anyway..

If you want to stub methods of the `dictionary' instance you have to configure your test class as follows:

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
MyDictionary dictionary;

@Test
public void testMyDictionary(){
    doReturn("value").when(dictionary).get("key);
    Assert.assertEquals("value", dictionary.get("key"));
}
```

Comment: When `MyDictionary.get(key) returns ""`, then I see a `MissingMethodInvocationException` because there is no mock object. When ``MyDictionary.get(key) returns map.get(key)`, the exception is not there. So the conclusion must be that although in the test I try to stub the `MyDictionary.get` method, in fact the `Map.get` method is stubbed (`map` is a mock).

Comment: All that happens in your original code right? Or also after my changes?

Comment: can I use when(dictionary.get(any())).thenReturn("value") ,Instead of 
begin with doReturn("value")