# @InjectMocks and @Spy together give RuntimeException

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, spy

I have two two methods in the class. I would like to test isolated only one of them.

So I am 'spying' invocation of the second method:

```
@Spy @InjectMocks private Manager manager;
//...
doReturn(obj).when(manager).method2(any());
```

I get `RuntimeException` here:

```
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot create a @Spy for 'manager' field because the *instance* is missing
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I did succesfully combine Spy and InjectMocks. Is Manager a class or an interface ?

Comment: Manager is a class

Comment: And has it a public parameterless Constructor?

Comment: yes it has public parameterless  Constructor

Comment: comment on the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38573651/3959856

Comment: I looked in my old project, sometimes i had to create the instance myself

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, @Spy can be used together with @InjectMocks.

Secondly, I encounter this problem too. when modified
`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` , I solved it.

Answer (score -1):

The right way to use would be to use it as

```java
@Spy
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
```