# Can't inject Bean (child of @Spy injected bean) in my Test

Tags: java, mockito

When I'm making a Test, I can't get injected a property of one of the injected beans (with *@Spy*). I am using *Mockito* to test.

I tried using `@Mock, @Spy, @SpyBean and @InjectMocks` in this Bean on my test but I can't get it injected.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest{

    @InjectMocks private MyService = new myService();
    @Spy private MyFirtsDepen firstDepen;
    @Autowired @Spy private ChildDepen childDepen;

    ... More mocks and tests
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired private MyFirstDepen firstDepen;
    ....
}

@Mapper
public class MyFirstDepen {
    @Autowired private ChildDepen childDepen;
    ....
}

@Component
public class ChildDepen {
    ... 
}
```

When my test use firstDepen is working great, but when firstDepen uses childDepend always get Nullpointer. How can I inject this property in my test?

Comment: If you got MyService as @Bean, why are you creating it yourself with `new myService()` ?

Comment: Have you tried `@InjectMocks @Spy private MyFirtsDepen firstDepen;`? **However**, why are you using a spy and not a mock for `MyFirstDepen`? I assume your service interacts just with it, so....

Answer (score 1):

Since your `MyFirtsDepen` is a mock, there is no way to inject anything to it. Configure mock to return another mock.

```
when(firstDepen.getChildDepen()).doReturn(childDepen);
```

Comment: Technically it's a spy as per `@Spy private MyFirtsDepen firstDepen;`, so you should be able to inject stuff into it...

Comment: How would you want to delegate field acces over spy to underlying object if field access is set??

Comment: It's certainly "_unorthodox_" but it works. Just try a quick sample with a couple of inner classes in a test, use `@InjectMoks` on the spy and you'll see the magic :-) ([more on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567326/is-it-discouraged-to-use-spy-and-injectmocks-on-the-same-field))