# Mock Interface Default Method

Tags: mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am trying to mock the default method (that uses SecurityContextHolder to get logged-in user) of the interface but not able to mock.

```java
public interface BaseController {

    /**
     * @return loggedInUser name
     */
    default String getLoggedInUser() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authentication.getName();
    }
}
```

```java
public class WPController implements BaseController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WPController.class);

    private WPService wpService;

    /**
     * @return ResponseEntity<List<WPDTO>>
     */
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<WPDTO>> getWPs() {
        LOG.debug("Calling.... all wp by user: {}", getLoggedInUser());
        final List<WPDTO> allWP = wpService.getAllWP();
        //LOG.debug("Called all wps by user: {}", getLoggedInUser());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(allWP );
    }
```

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class WPControllerTest {

    @Mock
    WPService wpService;

    @Mock
    private Logger loggerMock;

    @PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "javax.management.*", "javax.security.*"})
    @PrepareForTest({ LoggerFactory.class, BaseController.class })
    @Test
    public void  getWPsTest()
    {
        List<WPDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        WPDTO wpDTO= new WPDTO();
        wpDTO.setId(1);
        wpDTO.setDescription("Description");
        wpDTO.setLabel("Label");
        list.add(wpDTO);

        Authentication mockAuthentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);

        BaseController baseController = Mockito.mock(BaseController.class);
        PowerMockito.when(baseController.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn("Test User");

        mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
        PowerMockito.when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(WPServiceImpl.class)).thenReturn(loggerMock);

        Mockito.when(wpService.getAllWP()).thenReturn(list);

        WPController wpController = new WPController();
        wpController .setWPService(wpService);

        ResponseEntity<List<WPDTO>> response = wpController.getWPs();
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertTrue(response.getBody().size()>0);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.odigo.supervision.workspace.rest.BaseController.getLoggedInUser(BaseController.java:19)
    at com.odigo.supervision.workspace.rest.WorkspaceController.getWorkspaces(WorkspaceController.java:34)
    at com.odigo.supervision.workspace.rest.WorkspaceControllerTest.getWorkspacesTest(WorkspaceControllerTest.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use PowerMockito for this. You can make `WPController` a spy, which means it is real, but methods can be made into mocks. In this case, I think the easiest way to do it is to use `@InjectMocks` which makes a real `WPController` and replaces the real fields in it with any `@Mock` classes in the test class. Then also add `@Spy` to make it a spy. [Some people don't think that is a good pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567326/is-it-discouraged-to-use-spy-and-injectmocks-on-the-same-field), but I think it's the best solution for your design.

Once it is setup like this it's easy to override `getLoggedInUser()` to call a mock implementation.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class WPControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    WPController wpController;

    @Mock
    WPService wpService;

    @Test
    public void  getWPsTest()
    {
        List<WPDTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
        WPDTO wpDTO= new WPDTO();
        wpDTO.setId(1);
        wpDTO.setDescription("Description");
        wpDTO.setLabel("Label");
        list.add(wpDTO);

        Mockito.doReturn("Test User").when(wpController).getLoggedInUser();
        Mockito.when(wpService.getAllWP()).thenReturn(list);

        ResponseEntity<List<WPDTO>> response = wpController.getWPs();
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(wpDTO, response.getBody().get(0));
    }
}
```