# JUnit 5 and Mockito assertThrows() raises NullPointerException instead of original

Tags: java, junit5, junit-jupiter

I want to test a method which should throw a exception of type `MyCustomException`. This is an example of my class `MyService`.

```
public class MyService {
    public void invoke(InvocationContext ctx) throws MyCustomException{
        if(ctx == null) {
            throw new MyCustomException("Parameter ctx must not be null.");
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to test, whether method throws `MyCustomException` if I pass a null value with the `assertThrows()`.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AxwApplicationTest {
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    MyService myServiceToTest;

    @Test
    public void invoke_ShouldThrow_MyCustomException() {
        assertThrows(MyCustomException.class, () -> {
            myServiceToTest.invoke(null);
        });
    }
}
```

Somehow the exception is thrown but ends up as `NullPointerException` and I don't know how to solve it. The `assertThrows` gives my following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected exception type thrown; expected:<com.myproject.MyCustomException> but was:<java.lang.NullPointerException>
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wild guess no `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` on your test or using the wrong `@Test` (the one from JUnit4 instead of JUnit5). But as you posted only a partial snippet instead of the **full test** this is impossible to know.

Comment: @M.Deinum Added more details to the question.

Comment: I would expect the stack trace to give you a strong clue as to why you are getting NPE.

Comment: I would start by upgrade Mockito. 4.0.0 is a bit dated, I would at least try 4.11 or even switch to the 5.x releases. It is still not the full test case as I would expect some additional imports.

Comment: Your code should catch NPE and rethrow it as your type of exception.  Either that or if you get a NPE in your service have it throw your Exception type.

Comment: @M.Deinum Upgrading to 4.11 gives me detailed log, thank you!

Comment: Why `@Spy`? You are not spying on any calls nor stubbing calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the `@InjectMocks` and `@Spy` annotation. Using them together does not make sense (as discussed [in this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567326/is-it-discouraged-to-use-spy-and-injectmocks-on-the-same-field#:%7E:text=%40Spy%20and%20%40InjectMocks%20cannot%20be,them%20to%20the%20same%20object.)). Creating the class by hand solves the `NullPointerException` and the test runs successfully

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Spy;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static 
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
   MyService myServiceToTest;

   @Test
   public void invoke_ShouldThrow_MyCustomException() {
      MyService myServiceToTest = new MyService();
      assertThrows(MyCustomException.class, () -> {
        myServiceToTest.invoke(null);
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `@ExtendWith` with this (having that will actually slow down your test speed as it will scan the class for mockito annotations).