# How to inject an object created by @InjectMocks into another object created by @InjectMocks?

Tags: java, mockito

I have three services as follows:

```java
public class Service1 {
  private Service2 service2;
  private Service3 service3;
}

public class Service2 {
  private Service3 service3;
}

public class Service3 {

}
```

Now I use `@InjectMocks` to instance Service1 and I can inject Service2 and Service3 via `@Mock`:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
  @InjectMocks
  private Service1 service1;
   
  @Mock
  private Service2 service2;

  @Mock
  private Service2 service2;
}
```

But now the problem is that I want to create real Service2 and inject Service3 automatically, because i want to execute really method in Service2, just like `@InjectMocks`.

If I mark Service2 with `@Spy`, Service2 cannot actively inject `@Mock` marked Service3.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
  @InjectMocks
  private Service1 service1;
   
  // Service2 can not auto inject Service3
  @Spy
  private Service2 service2;

  @Mock
  private Service2 service2;
}
```

If I mark Service2 with `@InjectMocks`, Service2 cannot be actively injected into Service1, so is there any feasible way for me to achieve this?

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
  // Service1 can not auto inject Service2
  @InjectMocks
  private Service1 service1;
   
  @InjectMocks
  private Service2 service2;

  @Mock
  private Service2 service2;
}
```

Comment: checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300439/multiple-levels-of-mock-and-injectmocks)?

Comment: Why would you like to create 2 real instances with external mocks at 1 test? Please respect the (S!)OLID principle on your tests or create the services using the constructor call and no annotation.

Comment: Yes, I didn't follow Single Responsibility in test unit, it might be more reasonable to try to take apart